# Linux- Access files stored on an external hard drive using Python

Tags: python, linux, raspbian

Hi I'm trying to access files on an external hard drive connected to my Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian in order to put them up for sharing on a flask server.

I can't find a way to access files stored on the drive. I'd be grateful if anyone could tell me how external storage paths work in Raspbian as all the other questions like this one only worked for Windows or OS X.

Comment: Did you mount your disk as shown in this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/external-storage.md).  So, this basically mounts the externally connected drive as  a disk and then it can be accessed by specifying the directory path in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path is like this: /media/username/hard_drive/

You can access using above path or using `os` you can change your directory once like below.

```py
import os
os.chdir("path/to/hard/drive")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access files by simply specifying the full/absolute path in python. External drives appear as part of the file system in Linux.

To find out where your drive is mounted run `lsblk` to list all block devices. You will get output in the shape of:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:16   1  14.3G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:17   1   256M  0 part /boot
└─sda2   8:18   1  14.1G  0 part /
sdb      8:0    1 114.6G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:1    1 114.6G  0 part /media/<username>/<disk id>
```